# How to rerender {#each array} block in svelte after you push something to an array

Tags: javascript, svelte

Hello I'm making a comment section for my website which works but when I push an object to an array my `{#each}` block doesn't update here is this block of code

```html
            {#each commentsScript as { userName, rating, comment }, i}
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="w-1/4">
                        <h5>{userName}</h5>
                        <h5>{rating}</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-3/4">
                        <p>{comment}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {/each}
```

In my script section, I push a new comment to an array and it does show up after I refresh the page but I want to rerender it as soon as the user leaves a comment so the user would see hes/her own comment so is there any way I can rerender it?

Comment: How are you updating the array? Provide code for that.

Comment: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects 

You have to assign commentsScript = commentsScript if you are using push function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects

You have to assign `commentsScript = commentsScript`, which would be redundant normally, but that is how svelte works. This is true if you are using push function on array.

Comment: This doesn't work if the array is shared between components

Comment: Thanks a lot, saved me a lot of time. Makes sense, as the array itself is not changing, it's not firing a change detection. When you re-set the array, the change is detected!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to reassignment, there are several existing libraries that help you use the Array native APIs.

You can try this: https://svelte.dev/repl/0dedb37665014ba99e05415a6107bc21?version=3.53.1

use a library called svelox. It allows you to use the Array native api(push/splice...etc.) without reassignment statements.

Because it's weird to write a reassignment every time, this is something that every svelte beginner finds strange. Also, using the Array native APIs is not recommended(you should use spread).